# How much of `$.post` is blocking?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form collecting some information that I use `$.post` to handle an ajax request.

```
$.post(ajaxEndpoint, dataObject)
  .done(function (response) {
    if (response.status === 'success') {
      // Send data to process asynchronously
      otherApiCall(response.otherData);

      // Redirect to the thank you page
      window.location.replace(getThankYouUrl());
    }
  });

function otherApiCall (data) {
  $.post(otherAjaxEndpoint, data);
}
```

The problem I have, from what I'm guessing, is that it redirects too quickly before the other `POST` can be made. But I *do* want it to `POST` asynchronously then redirect so the user isn't waiting for that second response. I don't care what the result of the second response is. I just want to finish the first response, **send** a second `POST` and the redirect immediately to cut down on the user looking at a spinner.

My second `$.post` seems like it doesn't get sent in time before the redirect happens because I never get the data from it. If I comment out the redirect, I do. I don't want to wait until the second `done()` but I can't figure how not to. What am I not understanding and/or doing wrong?

### Additional Information/Update

I **do** have control over the server side handling. Is there something on that end that I could do to get a response quickly without waiting for the rest of the processing to finish?

Comment: On the server end, you could have it fork a new process to do the work, and have the main script exit.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to let the second post complete and then do the redirect.

A simple fix would be to return the `$.post` from second method and use `done()` of the second call to manage the redirect

```
$.post(ajaxEndpoint, dataObject)
  .done(function (response) {
    if (response.status === 'success') {
      // Send data to process asynchronously
      otherApiCall(response.otherData).done(function(){
          // second post call now complete
          // Redirect to the thank you page
          window.location.replace(getThankYouUrl());
      }).fail(function(){
           // handle failed response
       });      
    }
  });

function otherApiCall (data) {
  return $.post(otherAjaxEndpoint, data);
}
```

Comment: I know I can do that, but the question is how do I send it and *know* it's getting sent without using `done()`. I don't want to wait for the response, that's the idea

Comment: you can't know unless it completes

Comment: So then the answer to my question is, "it's not possible without using `done()`?" I don't care what the response is from the second one, I want to send it and move on, success or fail. The call could take a long time to finish and it's not necessary for the user to wait

Comment: @Grant - you can't know for sure that it was sent without either waiting for the response or waiting some predetermined time that you've tested in all popular browsers is long enough to make sure that the request had time to get sent (a hack) before you redirect.  Those are your two options.  If you control or can influence the server implementation, you can create a server call that returns immediately without waiting for the whole operation to be completed and then let the server finish the operation.  That way, the return is quick and confirmation is recieved.

Comment: @jfriend00, I do have access to the server (php) script. Could you give me an example answer of how to do that? Would a simple `echo` suffice?

Comment: @Grant yes a simple echo would suffice. Also consider that the amount of time to wait for response is not going to be very significant

Comment: @Grant - I don't know PHP myself, but the idea is that your PHP script sends the response to the API request immediately and then after that is sent, it goes about the longer task of processing the request.  Then, you will get that response very quickly in the client and can then do the redirect.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to send data back to a server without having to wait for it to complete would be to use the [`navigator.sendBeacon`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon) API.

```
navigator.sendBeacon('/url/to/handler', yourData);
```

Quote from MDN:

> Using the **`sendBeacon()`** method, the data will be transmitted asynchronously to the web server when the User Agent has had an opportunity to do so, without delaying the unload or affecting the performance of the next navigation.

Your data will have to be made into a [`ArrayBufferView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ArrayBufferView), [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob), [`DOMString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString), or [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData), and I'm not sure if it is technically a POST request or not, but the request will persist after redirection.

It is currently supported in Firefox 31+, Chrome 39.0+, Opera 26+. For other browsers, you would have to do something else. You can feature-detect like so.

```
if (navigator.sendBeacon) {
    // Use sendBeacon API.
}
else {
    // Something else.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The redirect is probably cancelling the AJAX request that has been queued, but not yet sent. Try doing the redirect after a timeout, to give the second AJAX call a chance to be sent.

```
$.post(ajaxEndpoint, dataObject)
  .done(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'success') {
      // Send data to process asynchronously
      otherApiCall(response.otherData);

      // Redirect to the thank you page
      setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.replace(getThankYouUrl());
      }, 10);
    }
  });
```

I'm not sure how reliable this is, though. Perhaps a better solution would be to perform the redirect when the second AJAX call goes to `readystate == 3`, which means the server is processing the request. There's no jQuery interface to this, so you'll probably have to do it using the low-level `XMLHttpRequest` interface.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that, but it kind of seems a _little_ hacky to me. I may be left with no options, though

Comment: I would expect the request would be cancelled by the redirect. No way of knowing if it finished sending or not.

Comment: Once it leaves the client, the server shouldn't care if the client is waiting for the response.

Comment: But no way of knowing if it successfully sent to the server in the delay. If connection was interrupted, it would fail.

Comment: My thinking is that since JS is single-threaded, it will completely finish sending the AJAX request before it processes the timeout entry in the queue.

Comment: Not necessarily, AFAIK there is no guarantee when the AJAX will actually send. The single-threaded nature of JavaScript does not extend to the environment.

Comment: I've added another option using `readystate == 3` to my answer.